# Multiple Sandbox Worker Process Proxy spawning

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sandbox-solution

I am setting up a new SharePoint 2013 dev vm (SP2013 SP1 and Sept 2014 CU) and I have enabled the Sandboxed Code Service in Central Admin. This causes multiple sandbox worker process proxy (SPUCWorkerProcessProxy.exe) to spawn, which keep spawning until all memory on the box is exhausted.

I found this article about a similar problem in 2010, [Blog](http://blogs.c5insight.com/Home/tabid/40/entryid/372/fix-for-high-cpu-with-multiple-spucworkerprocessproxy-and-conhost-with-sharepoint.aspx)

but it doesn't fix this problem.

I have also run process monitor and granted more permissions to keys in the registry that were flagged as being access denied, but again this hasn't helped.

I have increased the logging to verbose and in the ULS logs there are various messages (190 in total) linked to the `SPUCWorkerProcess` about an upgrade, e.g.

> "SharePoint Foundation Upgrade SPDelegateManager ajyyp DEBUG Registering [Microsoft.Office.Server.DLC.Upgrade.DlcPrejoinedFarmSequence] for [Microsoft.SharePoint.Administration.SPPrejoinedFarm], Phase: 2147483647, Order: 7."

Anyone have any ideas what might be wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Could you try to find all resources with denied of access to the SPUC processes using Process Monitor and filter as on the below screen [![enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVWiG.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BVWiG.png).